# How to access properties of skimage RAG

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I am doing image processing in python and am using the skimage rag_mean_color and segmentation methods to first segment the image. I then use graph.cut_threshold to merge adjacent regions with similar colors. At the end I have a very large region of a single color I want to extract. I have been using another method to try and get the most common color in the picture (kmeans) but am not getting the results I want.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the color of the region directly from the graph. Thanks!

RAG code:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
# convert the image to HSV 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
# apply the RAG thresholding on the image
labels1 = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=10, n_segments=600)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg')
# create the region adjacency graph from the labels and image
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels1)
# merge similar regions in the image/graph
labels2 = graph.cut_threshold(labels1, g, 20)
out2 = color.label2rgb(labels2, img, kind='avg')
# construct an updated graph for the image from the merged labels 
g2 = graph.rag_mean_color(out2, labels2)
# merge similar regions a second time to ensure like regions are merged 
labels3 = graph.cut_threshold(labels2, g2, 30)
out3 = color.label2rgb(labels3, out2, kind='avg')
```

This is the image I get:[image: Image after RAG]

Dominant Color Code:

```
# get the dominant (most common) color in an image using kmeans
# convert the image into HSV color space
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# reshape the photo to be rows of colors 
data = img.copy().reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)).astype(float)
# apply kmeans to the data
centroids, codes = kmeans2(data, 5)
# get the most common centroid
centroid = np.argmax(np.bincount(codes))
d_color = centroids[centroid].astype(np.uint8)
```

This is the color I get: [image: Dominant Color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Have a look at the [code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/75f74d567a5b65db5b0c1906f9ce88c127ba042a/skimage/future/graph/rag.py#L295-L383) for the `rag_mean_color` function. A RAG is a [NetworkX graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/introduction.html#graphs), so you can use that API to access the data. Specifically, `graph.node[idx]['mean color']` contains the mean color for node `idx`. You can also find the size in `graph.node[idx]['pixel count']`.